# Macro function call from within printf statement in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am facing a problem with understanding the use of macro function calls from within a printf() statement.

I have the code below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define f(g,h) g##h
main()
{
    printf("%d",f(100,10));
}
```

This code outputs "10010" as the answer.

I have learned that macro function call simply copy pastes the macro function code in place of the call with the arguments replaced.

So the code should be like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define f(g,h) g##h
main()
{
    printf("%d",100##10);
}
```

But when i executed the above code separately with substituted macro,i get a compilation error.

So how does the first code gives 10010 as the answer while the second code gives a compilation error?

Comment: The `##` ensures the parameters are concatenated. Therefore: f(100,10) is replaced by the preprocessor in: 10010

Comment: ## is only valid INSIDE your #define statement and has 'no effect' unless the line starts as '#define [your stuff here]', since the '#define' is what instructs the compiler to treat that part of code specially.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The preprocessor concatenation operator `##` is done *before* the macro is replaced. It can only be used in macro bodies.

Comment: Perfect . So that explains why the second code didnt work . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Operator `##` has speacial meaning for preprocessor, it's a token-paste operator which 'glues' two tokens together. So in your case, `g` and `h` are 'glued' together, resulting in new token - int literal `10010`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some special characters like `##` in a macro that change the rule 'simply substitutes text'.